# Frida: Print called functions

Tags: java, android, frida

Is there any way to print every function that is getting called when injecting code into Android apps using Frida?
Similar to the "onEnter" parameter when enumerating classes:

```
"onEnter": function(args){
       console.log("Function "+functionname+" got executed! Arguments: "+args)
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's not that trivial.

You can iterate Java.classes & extract methods using `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Java.use('com.company.CustomClass').__proto__)` and hook each one but there are limitations or use Frida's [Stalker](https://www.frida.re/docs/javascript-api/#stalker) & print each jump which in ARM it's branch or any move to PC register.

Take a look at Frida's creator comment on related topic
https://github.com/frida/frida/issues/244#issuecomment-286629943